# Creating moodle login for android app

Tags: php, android, moodle

I am developing an android application that interfaces with Moodle 2.5 platform. I need to enable users to login using the android app. These users are already created in the Moodle database. I can access the moodle database by creating my own PHP scripts and passing the username and passwords of the users. The only problem is that, the password encryption Moodle 2.5 uses is unknown to me. I need to know what method they used to encrypt their passwords so that my custom password verification can work. I know it uses bcrypt and i think md5 with some sort of salt string. Here is my PHP CODE:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$username=$_GET["username"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$saltedpassword=md5($password.$CFG->passwordsaltmain);
$count=$DB->count_records("user",array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$saltedpassword));
echo $count;
?>
```

It just wont work. Since the passwords do not match. My problem is, how do i generate the hash that moodle is using for the same. Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer. Do this:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$username=$_GET["username"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$response="";
$user=authenticate_user_login($username, $password);
if(!$user->username==""){
    $response="1";
}else{
    $response="0";
}
echo $response;
?>
```

Make sure you include the config.php Moodle file. Then access the authenticate_user_login Moodle authentication plugin function. DONE!!!
Thank you.